# Format a lookup to show blank if not found

Tags: ms-access, format, lookup

In MS Access I have a table containing a Long Integer field (TranService). This links to the ID column of another table (tServices). I have TranService defined as a lookup, so that it shows the description of the service, which works fine. However there are many records for which there isn't a related service, and in these cases TranService contains zero - and for these records the TranService column shows a "0". I would like such records to show blank in the TranService column, but I haven't managed to find a way of doing it.
Can you help, please?

Comment: Remove the zero - could be from the Format property. A lookup will by default return _Null_ for a value not found.

Comment: Remove 0 from DefaultValue property of field in table as well as control on form.  Then run an UPDATE or Find/Replace to eliminate 0 values from existing records. I also advise NOT to build lookups in table.

Comment: Reading question again - @Gustav makes a good point. TranService should show blank because of lookup since there is no description associated with 0. So how is it you are seeing 0? It may actually be in field but shouldn't show except in textbox, not in combobox on form. Report RecordSource should join tables and bind textbox to descriptive field so again, 0 should not show.